# OpenVPN works fine on windows but not everything on ubuntu

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have setup OpenVPN connection on windows and ubunt PCs. there are several websites I should be able to reach with this VPN connection and everything is fin with windows as I can reach them all. but from ubuntu I can reach only some of them. others gets me redirected like it was no VPN connection. does anyone knows what can be wrong?

Comment: You will need to share your OpenVPN server and client config files and logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had installed only openvpn using network manager using `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn` and everything was fine after that